# QGIS customize toolbars' plugin not consistent between sessions

Tags: qgis-3, qgis-plugins, toolbar

Currently using QGIS 3.22 (but it was also happening on 3.18), I created custom toolbars using Customize toolbar's (v1.1) plugins.

For one of these toolbar, I have one specific item "Add Point Feature" that would  disappear every time I open QGIS again (even if with a saved project).
Although it always appears in "My toolbars" settings...